# callback function doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript, callback

```
var res = "";
function longest(sen, callback) {
  sen = sen.split(" ");
  for(var i = 0; i < sen.length; i++) {
    callback(sen[i]);
  }
}

function findLongest(item) {
  if(item.length > res.length) {
    res = item;
  }
  return res;
}

longest("the greatest day EVERERAWEREWRWRAEWR",findLongest);
```

I'm trying to find the longest word in the string I input, but all it does is return undefined. I know there's a lot of easier ways to find the longest word, but I want to do it implementing a callback like such.

Comment: well you do not return....

Comment: does the return res not do anything?

Comment: You do not return from longest....

Comment: you are returning res from findLongest, but are doing nothing with it in longest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`longest` updates `res` (via the callback) but does not return anything. Try printing out `res` after your call to `longest`, or returning `res` from `longest`.

Comment: when I try to return res from longest, I keep getting "res is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

```js
var res = "";
function longest(sen, callback) {
  sen = sen.split(" ");
  for(var i = 0; i < sen.length; i++) {
    callback(sen[i]);
  }
}

function findLongest(item) {
  if(item.length > res.length) {
    res = item;
    console.log('now max len is %s',item);
  }
}

longest("the greatest day EVERERAWEREWRWRAEWR",findLongest);
```

remove return,since you don't use it. replace with console.log so you can see result.